# Custom ul class

Tags: menus, navigation

I need help for my custom Wordpress Layout.
It should look like this (HTML):

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
             <a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
             <a href="#services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
             <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In Wordpress:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?page_id=2">Test/Site</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My Code:

```
<?php 
   wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse' ) ); 
?>
```

Comment: Have you defined a menu for the primary menu location? If not, WP will default to `wp_page_menu()` which will not use the same `menu_class` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Menu class is `nav navbar-nav` not `collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse`.

```
wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav'));
```

Comment: Doesn't work.    `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <div class="nav navbar-nav"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?page_id=2">Example</a></li></ul></div>
                </div>` Ul must have `class="nav navbar-nav"`

Comment: <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav')); ?> 
</div>

Comment: not woking. Your code set the div class, not the ul class. Self result.
`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"> <div class="nav navbar-nav"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?page_id=2">Example</a></li></ul></div> </div>`

Comment: `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
<?php $args = array(
 'theme_location'  => '',
 'menu'            => '',
 'container'       => 'div',
 'container_class' => '',
 'container_id'    => '',
 'menu_class'      => 'menu',
 'menu_id'         => '',
 'echo'            => true,
 'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
 'before'          => '',
 'after'           => '',
 'link_before'     => '',
 'link_after'      => '',
 'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="nav navbar-na">%3$s</ul>',
 'depth'           => 0,
 'walker'          => ''
);
 wp_nav_menu( $args ); 
?> 
</div>`

Comment: In the future, please update your answer in response to comments, especially if you're modifying code samples. It's a lot easier to read when you have the luxury of using line breaks.